# What's the difference between "class" and "case class" in Stream in Scala?

Tags: class, scala, case-class

```
class A(x: Int)
def f(a: A): Stream[A] = a #:: f(new A(a.x + 1))

case class B(x: Int)
def f(b: B): Stream[B] = b #:: f(B(b.x + 1))
```

I expected these two cases would do the same action. But the former failed with an error(value x is not member of A). Why does only the former fail?

Comment: This issue doesn't have anything to do with `Stream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case class has its constructor parameters automatically made into accessible fields. For example, your class `B` has `x` as a field and so `B.x` is legal. Your class `A` is not a case class and so its `x` was not made into an accessible field. If you want a non-case class to have its constructor parameters accessible they must be explicitly marked with `val`:

```
class A(val x: Int)
```